# Node.js Backend to handle high loads

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, google-cloud-functions, devops, serverless

I am about to build a web application that should be able to handle a heavy amount of HTTP requests, (500k per minutes for edge cases)

The application's logic is pretty simple and besides simple CRUD to the database no much other logic required. So it can be a really small and simple express application for example.

So my question is, what platform/architecture should I choose?
Should it be node.js application that could be scale with pm2 (and if so, what are the required machine I need? CPU, RAM, etc) or should I consider serverless approach? cloud functions / lambdas.

I have a pretty nice budget for this project but I do not want to reach over 1k$ per month to maintain this.

Since we are a small team here and don't have DevOps guy on our side I am aiming to have it as managed as possible.

Thank you all in advance! any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: To deploy an app to production I would suggest to use nginx and proxy and load balance to your apps. Static content if you will provide any, can be handled and cached by nginx as well to reduce compute resources.

Here is a guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: Such questions are too broad for StackOverflow, and often invite extended debate. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com is a better choice for such design problems.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure that this answer can be right or not for you, but this depends on how you imagine to use your budget regarding to your project.

In my case, for the large amount of requests (~500K/minutes) I would use Firebase Functions (serverless) approach.

For first 2M invocations it will be free, and after that it will cost [$0.40/million](https://firebase.google.com/pricing).

Calculated ($ 0.0000004 for 1 invocation):

```
0.0000004 * 500000 * 60 * 24 * 30 = 8640
```

This might be very huge for you, but as you said 500K is just for edge cases. If it will coas $ 1-2K for average cases, then I would use that in that situation, cuz it gives guarantees for stability and scalability.
Anyway it's up to you, so I'll leave some resources about usage and something like that.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing#invocations) is the detailed pricing plans. There's already described about appropriate CPUs, Memories and other stuff. I don't think that's very huge for solving this exact situation.

For usage of firebase functions you can follow to these guides (from firebase-developers):

- [A Practical Approach to Cloud Functions for Firebase: Setup](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/a-practical-approach-to-cloud-functions-for-firebase-an-introduction-d3b5ae2114e7)
- [Migrate your Firebase Cloud Functions to Node.js 10](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/migrate-your-firebase-cloud-functions-to-node-js-10-d9c677933ee)

Or for practical usage (video):

- [Full Stack React & Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TDSYo0JaIEk&list=PLMhAeHCz8S38ryyeMiBPPUnFAiWnoPvWP&index=13)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer! would take a look at those as well. What do you think about DigitalOcean App Platform? it seems to be managed and easily scaled, does anyone have an experience with that?